# How to make parts of a div element resize automatically?

Tags: layout, html, resize

I'm trying to create a small html fragment (a `div` element) consisted of three parts: a label, textbox, and a button.

Within that div element the label would be on the left (autosized), the button would be on the right (again, autosized) and the textbox should take up all remaining space within the parent `div` element.

This is what I've tried (assuming I want my `div` to be 400 pixels wide):

```
<div style="width:400px">
    <div style="float: left">Label</div>
    <input style="width:100%">  <!-- doesn't work -->
    <button type='button' style='float: right'>Click</button>
</div>
```

The trouble is, my textbox does not get resized automatically. Add 'width=100%' to the textbox doesn't work.

What would be the way to make it take up all remaining space between the label and the button? Ideally it should be done just by applying some styles, not by introducing new elements.

(I guess the issue isn't related only to `div` element, but that just happens to be my work scenario.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps something like this will be what you want. Yeah I know it's cheating. And yeah, I agree with @Paul re: label, so i swiped his id. :)

**EDIT:** Obligatory [Self-Referencing Demo](http://jsbin.com/igiru/)

Warning: not tested in all browsers.

**CSS:**

```
div {
  display: table;
  width: 400px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

label {
  display: table-cell;
  padding-right: 3px;
  width: 1em;
}

input {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 100%;
}

span {
  display: table-cell;
  padding-left: 6px;
  width: 1em;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div>
  <label for="my-very-special-input">Label</label>
  <input id="my-very-special-input"/>
  <span><button type="button">Click</button></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The only way I could think of making this work was with percents. I enclosed everything in seperate divs (probably uneccesary) and then assigned percentages to each div. Take a look:

```
<div style="width=400px">
<div style="float:left; width:10%">Label</div>
<div style="float: left; width:70%"><input style="width:100%"></div>  <!-- doesn't work -->
<div style="float: right width:20%"><button type='button' style=''>Click</button></div>
```

It's by no means a perfect solution, but hopefully it will suit your needs to some extent.

Elliott

Answer (score 1):

Does it help if you wrap the `<input>` in a `<div>` with `overflow: hidden`?

```
<div style="width: 400px;">
    <div style="float: left;">Label</div>
    <div style="overflow: hidden;">
        <input style="width: 100%;">
    </div>
    <button type="button" style="float: right;">Click</button>
</div>
```

See [xHTML/CSS: How to make inner div get 100% width minus another div width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2198116/xhtml-css-how-to-make-inner-div-get-100-width-minus-another-div-width/2251833#2251833).

And although it’s off-topic, please note that your label should be, well, a `<label>`.

```
<div style="width: 400px;">
    <label for="my-very-special-input" style="float: left;">Label</label>
    <div style="overflow: hidden;">
        <input id="my-very-special-input" style="width: 100%;">
    </div>
    <button type="button" style="float: right;">Click</button>
</div>
```