# CSS: Two divs - one fills space, one shrink-to-fit

Tags: css, layout, html

Is there a way to have two divs placed next to each other so that:

- The width of the outer div is unknown
- The rightmost div atapts its width to its content (shrink-to-fit)
- The leftmost div fills the remaining space

I see that Paul D. Waite has almost cut it here:
[xHTML/CSS: How to make inner div get 100% width minus another div width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2198116/xhtml-css-how-to-make-inner-div-get-100-width-minus-another-div-width/2251833#2251833)

In my case, the two inner divs need to switch places, and I just can't cut it.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Simply change `float: left` to `float: right` in Paul's example.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="outer">
    <div id="adaptive">I will adapt my width to my content.</div>
    <div id="filler">I will fill the remaining space.</div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#outer { overflow: hidden; width: 100%; }
#adaptive { float: right; }
#filler { overflow: hidden; }
```

[Test jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/br3vu/)

Comment: that won't do it, you also need to change the order of the divs in the HTML otherwise the right floated div is under the other one. I just tried it in jsfiddle.

Comment: Thanks Bazz, but have you actually checked my jsFiddle? In both cases the floated div should come first, so what's wrong with only changing `left` to `right`?

Comment: Thanks. See my reply to Bazzz.

Comment: @Anders I don't really think it matters that much. If you really want to stick to it, you could switch them with Javascript.

Comment: @bazmegakapa The rightmost div will contain a "Read more"-like button in several forms. It will seem odd codewise, but again, js may come to resque.

Comment: @Anders I guess if you give correct `TITLE`s to your "Read more" buttons you will have no problems.

Comment: absolutely beautifull. this is exactly what i needed. thank you mister

Answer (score 2):

Here you go:

http://jsfiddle.net/BhAcn/1/

Paul Waite's example fitted to your question

```
#outer {
    overflow: hidden;/* Makes #outer contain its floated children */
    width: 100%;
}

#inner1 {
    float: right;/* Make this div as wide as its contents */
}

#inner2 {
    overflow: hidden;/* Make this div take up the rest of the horizontal space, and no more */
}
```

Comment: Hm, no offense, but you posted the same fiddle as mine :). I am always ready to be corrected, but seems like you just did the exact same thing.

Comment: Thanks. Still, the order of the divs seems a little bit odd. For semantics and screen reader usability, I would prefer that the leftmost placed div was the first in the code.

Comment: @bazmegakapa we worked on it at exactly the same time. Have a look at our posting times, they are 1 minute off. Your post wasn't there yet when I started.

Comment: @Bazzz I just saw your comment under my answer first, and after that I saw your answer added. It just seemed to me that you wanted to correct me with your answer. Still, no offense, these things happen :).

Comment: @bazmegakapa none taken, I added my answer and noticed that yours (Simply change float:left to float:right) was missing the aspect that I mentioned (divs the other way around), so I added the comment. After that, I think you reviewed and updated your answer and the OP managed to get the right solution to his issue. I never meant to offend anyone.

Comment: @Bazzz Fair enough, me neither.

Answer (score -2):

Try this....

**Html:**

```
<div id="outer">
 <div id="inner-left">
  <p>hello</p>
 </div>
 <div id="inner-right">
  <p>hello1</p>
 </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
<style type="text/css">
    #outer
    {
        width:100%;
        height:100%;
        border:1px solid black;
    }
    #inner-left
    {
        width:75%;
        float:left;
        border:5px solid black;
    }
    #inner-right
    {
        width:200px;
        float:left;
        border:5px solid black;
    }

    </style>
```

Hope this helps!!!

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But the width of the divs are hardcoded, and wont adapt to their content.