# Expanding DIVS that are inline

Tags: css

I am trying to get 2 divs to sit side by side, with one of the divs expanding to fill empty space.

The site I am working on has a link, with a colour block beside it. The colour block should remaining width of the div, depending on how much space the link text takes up.

Originally, I tried floating Divs side by side but this didn't work when lowering the screen size. I have also tried inline-block but this didn't work either.

Finally, I tried the resolution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5893736/css-two-divs-one-fills-space-one-shrink-to-fit), again this did not work. Where am I am going wrong?

My code is:

```
<div class="link-wrapper">

    <div class="block yellow">
    </div><!--/ Block -->

    <div class="link">
        <p><a href="#</a></p>
    </div><!--/ Link -->

</div>
```

CSS is:

```
.link-wrapper{
    width:100%;
    overflow:hidden;}

.block{
    overflow:hidden;
    height:15px;}

.link{
    float:right;}
```

Comment: Which part of your site you got problem with?

Comment: Please post the relevant code in the question.

Comment: "Talk is cheap, show me the code".

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: The section I am working on is towards the bottom - there are three columns with a link in each one.

Comment: @CharlyAnderson - I guessed correctly - see my answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll be guessing here - my crystal ball told me that you need this :)

**HTML:**

```
<div class="link-wrapper">
     <div class="block yellow">
          <div class="link">
               <p><a href="#">Look Book '15</a> &gt; &gt;</p>
          </div><!--/ Link -->
     </div><!--/ Block -->   
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.block {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 21px;
}
.link {
  float: right;
  background: #F1F1F1;
  padding-left: 10px;
}
```

So basically - I don't think you can set both divs, to sit next to each other, without explicitly fixing the width of at least one of them, and then using `calc()` function to do necessary calculation. Above code mimicks this look, but with slightly different html structure, where link is a child of colourful parent `div` element.

**EDIT:**

As per comment there is an option to use a `flex box`, to avoid changing `html`:

```
/* Flexbox way */

.link-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.block {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 21px;
  flex-grow: 2;
}
.link {
  float: right;
  padding-left: 10px;
}
```

Where `flex-grow` is important bit which does the job here - "it defines the ability for a flex item to grow if necessary".

So you have pretty good choice here:
1 - to modify markup, and nest link inside parent div, or
2 - if you don't worry about too extensive browser support, you could use flex- box without need of touching your html

Comment: This actually works perfectly, not sure why I didn't think of it myself! Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: No problem - while I think about it now, you could actually tried to work it out with [flexbox](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/), and this would allow you to keep your previous html structure - but everything depends on browsers you need to support, as [flex support is not universal](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox)