# Css - Don't want elements below my floated element

Tags: html, css, overflow, css-float, hidden

I have a floated div with "sidebar" text. Its parent container has text as well.
I don't want to have text below my floated "sidebar" div:

[example http://img864.imageshack.us/img864/6058/screenshot2011052613084xv.png](http://img864.imageshack.us/img864/6058/screenshot2011052613084xv.png)

How can I fix this?

```
<div id="parent">
    <div id="floated" style="float:right">Foo bar</div>
    <h2>Foo</h2>
    <p>Text!</p>
</div>
```

Comment: The big red no gave me a little laugh.

Answer (score 3):

If it doesn’t mess up anything else, you can use `overflow: hidden` or `overflow: auto` to fix this:

```
<div id="parent">
    <div id="floated" style="float:right">Foo bar</div>
    <div class="next-to-float" style="overflow: hidden;">
        <h2>Foo</h2>
        <p>Text!</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/pauldwaite/YL5P3/

I’ve written about this more fully here, including code to make it work in IE 6: [xHTML/CSS: How to make inner div get 100% width minus another div width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2198116/xhtml-css-how-to-make-inner-div-get-100-width-minus-another-div-width/2251833#2251833)

I still don’t really understand the reasoning behind *why* `overflow: hidden` does this, but I understand that it does follow from the CSS spec.

Comment: And hide his text? I think that solution is *not* optimal :)

Comment: It doesn't hide the text. This is a good solution. I always used to do what Robert Koritnik suggest, but this is simpler.

Comment: Make sure you use a doctype, else this wont work. And this doesn't work in IE6, so perhaps the margin solution is better.

Comment: @Paul: Sorry to downvoted you. This actually works. I don't know why it works but is seems to support even flexible width floated elements which makes this solution **the best solution**. If you change your answer in some way I will be able to revoke my down-vote. And rather upvote. Is this behaviour the same over major browsers? Where does the CSS spec say that this should work as it does with floated elements. Interesting...

Comment: @Michael: it would indeed hide any text that overflows the element, but I don’t think that’s likely to occur in this example. I have added `overflow: auto` as another option; I’m not entirely sure that works in IE though.

Comment: @Robert: that’s alright, it is a very obscure part of CSS. It is pretty handy if you don’t know the width of the element that’s floated, but in general, I think you would, and setting a margin with an explicit width (like you suggested I think) makes the CSS a bit more self-explanatory IMHO. This works in most browsers; in IE 6 you can achieve the same behaviour with `zoom: 1` and a margin fix. I’m led to understand that this behaviour does follow from the CSS spec, but it’s quite obscure.

Comment: Upvoted your other answer which actually seems to be a duplicate of this questions.

Comment: @Robert: yeah, it’s one of those questions that can come up in a million different ways that don’t sound anything like each other. Describing layouts with words is a nightmare.

Comment: @Paul: Thanks for editing your answer so I was able to convert my down-vote into an up-vote. Your answer should be accepted actually. I learned something completely new (also a bit confusing) as well.

Comment: @Robert: no worries at all, thank you for re-voting. I still think your solution is a bit clearer (and avoids clipping any overflowing content), so given the likelihood that the floated element will have a fixed width, I’d go with yours. It’s good to know about the `overflow: hidden` option if you do need that flexibility on widths though.

Answer (score 2):

### Set right margin on non-floated element

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bA8RD/1)

The only requirement is that you must predefine your floated element's width. Then it can have whatever height you like and the non-floated content (when applied right margin) won't stretch under floated element.

### How it works?

1. We have floated element on the right with **width = X**
2. We have usual content but set its **right margin = X+s** where s is some predefined space between your content and floated element so they don't touch.

And that's it.

Since you have multiple content elements (heads, paragraphs) you have to put them inside a container with this right margin setting.

```
<div id="parent">
    <div id="floated">Foo bar</div>
    <div id="content">
        <h2>Foo</h2>
        <p>Text!</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

And CSS:

```
#floated
{
    float: right;
    padding: 1em;
    background: #ccc;
    width: 10em;
}

#content
{
    margin-right: 13em; /* 10em width + 2 x 1em padding + 1em space */
}
```

### Why is this solution better than setting main content width?

Because setting main content width will only work when you want to limit your document content to a fixed width (like 960 grid). But when you want your content to stretch over the whole browser window width, this solution will work regardless of browser window size.

### And a small advice

Avoid using inline styles whenever possible because maintainability of your application/site will become a nightmare.

Answer (score 0):

You can nest 2 div tags inside the container. Float them both and resize them as you need them to be.

Answer (score 0):

Set a bottom margin on the floated element that equals the length of the remainder. Or add a width to the larger element and float it the other direction.

```
<div id="parent">
    <div id="floated" style="width:200px; float:right">Foo bar</div>
    <div id="content" style="width:600px; float:left">
        <h2>Foo</h2>
        <p>Text!</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

OR

```
<div id="parent">
    <div id="floated" style="width:200px; margin-bottom:200px; float:right">Foo bar</div>
    <h2>Foo</h2>
    <p>Text!</p>
</div>
```

Comment: When content is an undefined amount of text it's hard to predict what the reminder size is so your second solution is not an option really.

Answer (score 0):

its easy simply add width in [P] tag see here

**example**

```
<div id="parent">
    <div id="floated" style="float:right">Foo bar</div>
    <h2>Foo</h2>
    <p style=" width: 500px; ">Text!</p>
</div>
```

for example your ( id="parent" ) have 800px width

and  (id="floated") right-side bar have 200px width

then make your [P] 800px - 200px = 600px

so set your [P] width to 600px

----------  or

if you want some space between text and bar make [P] width 580px

it means 20px for space