# Why a float right div is floating inside the next div?

Tags: css, html, css-float

I was hoping I wasn't a beginner with css, but I can't understand why the following happens...

You can see an example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/prejR/)

I wish to display 2 separated div on the same "line" :

- First div must 100% width to the second
- Second div at the extrem right of the first

So, I've done the following

```
// CSS
.div2 {
    background:#EDEDED;
    float:right;    
}
.div1  {    
    background:#CCC;
}
.div1, .div2 {
    padding:4px;
    margin:4px;
}
.round {
    -webkit-border-radius:8px;
    -moz-border-radius:8px;
    border-radius:8px;
    border:1px solid #000;
}
// HTML
<div class="div2 round">Test 2</div>
<div class="div1 round">Test 1</div>
```

But the .div2 is inside the first div...
[image: Bad display]

How to display something like following ? (Like I thought it should be displayed...)
[image: Good display]

Any help appreciated...

**EDIT : SOLUTION**
By [user570783](https://stackoverflow.com/users/570783/user570783)

```
.div1 {overflow:hidden;}
```

Work like a charm, but not really documented, why this works ?

Comment: Add overflow: hidden; to the div1 style.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2198116/xhtml-css-how-to-make-inner-div-get-100-width-minus-another-div-width

Comment: @user570783 Perfect answer ! Thanks a lot. Write it in an answer then I could accept it please.

Comment: I posted an answer, but was turned into a comment because it was too short. Anyway, it would be useful to include in the answer where is this behaviour documented in the css standard. I really don't understand why this works.

Answer (score 2):

float does what is says. float. as in stuff can be underneath it. Text will be wrapped, but borders won't

if you know the width of "Test 2", you can add a "margin-right: x;"

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I can't know the div1 or div2 width

Answer (score 2):

OK, there are many solutions here involving, floats, inline-block, margins and borders but all require knowledge of at least one element's size.

However!

There's a trick you can do here.  If you add 'overflow:hidden' to the first div it will force the div to '[block formatting context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6196725/how-does-the-css-block-formatting-context-work)'

This will get the result you're after, with dynamic sized right floating element.

To make this work in IE5 and 6 you need to trigger 'hasLayout' on the first element, so position: relative;

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/prejR/12/)

Comment: at the time of writing this i didn't see that someone else had answered it in the comments! gj user570783