# Make center div take remaining screen with bottom div taking as much space as needed

Tags: css, html

This is somewhat related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2198116/xhtml-css-how-to-make-inner-div-get-100-width-minus-another-div-width) but I'm trying to achieve this when the div is aligned vertically.

More or less, this is what I'm trying to achieve:

### Main Div: Take the rest of the screen

---

### Footer Div: Take as much space as needed

The css for float:bottom isn't available, so I'd like to hear some alternatives.

Here's what I have at the moment:

```
<div id="main_div" style="height:100%;overflow:scroll">
...Contents
</div>

<div id="footer_div" style="height:50px">
...Contents
</div>
```

Footer shows below main_div and the user has to scroll down to see it, instead of main_div adjusting itself to take just enough screen height to prevent the scrollbar to show up.

Comment: @BhushanFirake There you go.

Comment: Why not you use `position absolute`. Both the `divs` give position absolute. Let me know?

Comment: @Sarfaraz I'm not sure if I understood you correctly, but you are asking me to set the position as absolute in both divs, right? Doing so hides the footer div.

Comment: what am understand by your question let me make a fiddle and show it to you give me 5 mins.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/sarfarazdesigner/3fLca/ check this fiddle

Answer (score 1):

you can check this fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/sarfarazdesigner/3fLca/

let me know am understand right or wrong? because what i have done what i understood by your question.

```
#main_div{
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    top:0;
    bottom:50px;
    overflow:auto;
    background:#eee;
}
#footer_div{
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
    background:#ddd;
    height:50px;
}
```

Comment: YES!! Worked perfectly. Thank you so much.

Comment: Wait, this doesn't work on IE 9. I've created a minimal example demonstrating this http://www.mediafire.com/view/?pv4upua28a70m58.

Comment: yes you are right that is not working in ie9 sorry for inconvenience i have not test it in other browser let me check this give me some time thanks

Comment: No problem, take your time. Thanks a lot for trying to help.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the footer a fixed position at the bottom of the page. Any overlapping content will scroll behind it.

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="wrapper" style="width: 100%; border:1px solid blue;"> 
            <p>Your website content here.</p>
            <p>Your website content here.</p>
            <p>Your website content here.</p>
            <div class="push"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="footer" style="width: 100%; position:fixed; left:0; bottom: 0; border:1px solid red;">
            <p>FOOTER CONTENT HERE</p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is what I thought too, but it doesn't work for some reason. Please see my edit.

Comment: Tried, but still the problem is there.

Comment: Your edit fixes the footer in position correctly, but when the main div makes a scrollbar, the content gets overlapped with the footer, making it look quite dirty.